# Only allow a certain amount of touchPointIds

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

In touchEvents, they handle multi touches, right?  So you can use multiple fingers at once.  So how do I only allow the event to handle a certain amount of touches?  For example, only drag 3 squares, not all five? (Example, not what I'm doing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AS3 you can use `TouchEvent.touchPointID`. From the official docs:

> The Flash runtime assigns each point of touch a unique `touchPointID`
>   value.
>   ...
>   Use the `touchPointID` property to manage an entire touch sequence. A touch sequence has one `touchBegin` event, zero or more `touchMove` events, and one `touchEnd` event that all have the same `touchPointID` value.

Basically you should track only the touch sequences you are interested in (eg: only 3 different touches at the same time). So you could use an index to store those ids and let your touch handlers check against it in order to skip a particular sequence or not.

Some quick sketched code:

```
// allocate a counter and a dictionary to be used as a whitelist and
var sequencesLeft : int = 3;
var currSequences : Dictionary = new Dictionary();

...

mySprite..addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, onTouchBegin);
mySprite..addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE, onTouchMove);
mySprite..addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, onTouchEnd);

...

function trackSequence(event:TouchEvent, add : Boolean = false) : Boolean {
  if( add && counter == 0 )
    return false;

  var val : String = currSequence[ event.touchPointID ];
  if( add && !val ) {
    currSequences[ event.touchPointID ] = "" + counter--;
    return true;
  }

  return val != null;
}

function onTouchBegin(event:TouchEvent) {
  trackSequence( event, true );
}

function onTouchMove(event:TouchEvent) {
  if( !trackSequence( event ) )
    return;
  else {
    /* do whatever you want */
  }
}

function onTouchEnd(event:TouchEvent) {
  if( trackSequence( event ) ) {
    delete currSequences[ event.touchPointID ];
    counter++;
  }
}
```